# Custom converters in Scallop library

Tags: scala, reflection

I am trying to use Scallop (https://github.com/scallop/scallop/) to parse the command-line arguments in Scala.

However, I cannot compile the example for converting arguments to a case class as shown on https://github.com/scallop/scallop/wiki/Custom-converters.

I get two errors at compile-time:

```
[error]  found   : org.rogach.scallop.ValueConverter[center.scala.sbk.Commands.Person]{val nameRgx: scala.util.matching.Regex; val phoneRgx: scala.util.matching.Regex}
[error]  required: String
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     val person = opt[Person](personConverter)
[error]                              ^
```

and

```
[error] ...: could not find implicit value for parameter conv: org.rogach.scallop.ValueConverter[center.scala.sbk.Commands.Person]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     val person = opt[Person](personConverter)
[error]                             ^
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation has a typo.
Use

```
val person = opt[Person]()(personConverter) // note the parentheses
```

instead of

```
val person = opt[Person](personConverter)
```

since `personConverter` is passed in implicit arguments.